# using static variables to initialize variables in the same class

Tags: javascript, dojo, mootools

I am trying to emulate this following behavior of Java with Javascript using `mootools/Dojo`. A instance variable that needs to be initialized with a class static variable value.

```
Class xyz {
    public static static_constants {
        TEST_CONST1 : "abc";
    }

    private a = static_constants.TEST_CONST1;
}
```

I can do it the way below, but then `com.example.test.static_constants.TEST_CONST1` will not exist anymore as we have overwritten `com.example.test`. But if `com.example.test.static_constants.TEST_CONST1` is not defined earlier, the assignment with-in the class will fail.

```
com.example.test.static_constants.TEST_CONST1 = "abc";

var com.example.test = new Class ({
    a : com.example.test.static_constants.TEST_CONST1
});
```

Two workarounds that work:

## (I) - have separate instance variable inside the class; and use static outside

```
var com.example.test = new Class ({
    static_constants : {
        TEST_CONST1 : "abc"
    },
    a : this.static_constants.TEST_CONST1
});

com.example.test.static_constants.TEST_CONST1 = "abc";
```

## (II) recreate the static after class is defined

```
com.example.test.static_constants.TEST_CONST1 = "abc";

var com.example.test = new Class ({
    a : com.example.test.static_constants.TEST_CONST1
});

com.example.test.static_constants.TEST_CONST1 = "abc";
```

What am I missing?  Both these ways don't seem clean to me. There must be a cleaner way to do this (without using extend etc - which will further break the class).

Comment: What *version* of Dojo are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I interject and stop you right there.

JavaScript is not JAVA. The fact that you need to not use JAVA now does not mean you need to move the crap associated with namespaces and statics and patterns that it has over to JavaScript. JavaScript has different patterns when it comes to doing things.

In any case, since you did not ask what the best pattern for organising stuff and Classes in MooTools are and you just want to know how to mutate and extend your existing object, you can do this small factory:

http://jsfiddle.net/vrKX2/4/

```
var com = {
    example: {
        test: {
            static_constants: {
                TEST_CONST1: "abc"
            }
        }
    }
};

Class.extend({
    fromExisting: function(namespace, constructorObject){
        return Object.append(new this(constructorObject), namespace);
    }
});

// this is non-DRY. It kind of is Object.merge()
com.example.test = Class.fromExisting(com.example.test, {

    a: com.example.test.static_constants.TEST_CONST1,
    initialize: function(){
        console.warn(this.a);
    },
    getStatic: function(what){
        return com.example.test.static_constants[what];
    }
});

var t = new com.example.test();
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(t)); // no static_constants
console.log(t.a);
console.log(com.example.test.static_constants);
com.example.test.static_constants.TEST_CONST1 = 'bbb';
console.log(t.a);
console.log(t.getStatic('TEST_CONST1'));
```

`Class.fromExisting` will accept some object, which it will merge its properties against the class constructor object (but static, not on the prototype) - but it cannot mutate the obj it is extending in the constructor (can't think of why right now but it's saturday night).

you really ought to just implement a more sensible module naming approach / namespacing - like in AMD and use `constants` on a separate config object. there is no need to mix the two namespaces - or indeed, the need to namespace at all when you use AMD (though you can name your modules).

**Please don't use this factory pattern, just shows how flexible mootools can be when extending types etc.**

Instead, you can simply do - as mentioned - just `Object.merge()`

```
com.example.test = Object.merge(new Class({
    a: com.example.test.static_constants.TEST_CONST1,
    initialize: function(){
        console.warn(this.a);
    },
    getStatic: function(what){
        return com.example.test.static_constants[what];
    }
}), com.example.test);
```

since you are working with some dodgy namespaces, you want to look at extending Object Type (not the prototype of Object) with get/set that work deep, Daniel Buchner tried to land it but was shot down.

https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/pull/2191/files

these may take away the pain of creating deeper namespaces from dotted strings. have fun now.

Comment: @Sergio like I said, MooTools just imploded because everybody really wanted a change but wouldn't do it themselves, yet liked to critique anything else happening. only one thing could come out of it: code/feature freeze. it did. this particular feature came about because they shot down my PR for `String.substituteFromPath()` after initial enthusiasm so Daniel thought Object.set/get would solve both... never mind. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're [using AMD](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/modules/), you would `define` a module without creating a global object chain like `com.example.test`. The documentation for `declare` has [a short section on static objects](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/declare.html#static-objects), but the concept is straightforward: you can hang "extras" off of the module you return.

If you need a constant that's only available to the module it is defined in, just use a regular variable. If you need access to it *outside* of the module, just hang it off the module object that you return. This is similar to the first method in your question, but there's no need to involve an ugly chain of global objects.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd break down your problem in two two separate issues:

1. How to set **instance** properties from **static** properties (constant or otherwise)
2. How to create convenient **constant** properties (whether instanced or static)

No matter what you do it's going to be a little bit ugly, due to the architectural differences between JS and Java.

---

## Static properties

The key here is that you have to delay your attempt to access the static variable until an instance is actually being created. I don't know about mootools (is it `initialize`?), but in Dojo 1.9 the relevant method is called `constructor`, so that's what I'm going to use in this example:

```
var makeMyClass = function(){

    var clazz = new Class ({
        instanceVal : null, // Don't know what to put here yet

        constructor : function(){
            /* 
            I know this looks weird that this property is ALSO 
            called "constructor", but it works in Dojo 1.9. Consult
            your debugger to see if a similar tactic works in mootools.
            */
            var selfClass = this.constructor; 
            
            // Remember that if staticVal is an object, you may-or-may-not want an independent copy
            this.instanceVal = selfClass.staticVal;
        }
    });

    clazz.staticVal = "Hello World";
    return clazz;
};
    
var com.example.myClass = makeMyClass();
```

Now if you modify `com.example.myClass.staticScalarVal` it should influence classes constructed in the future, although IMO a builder or factory design pattern would be much better.

---

## Constants

The implementation here strongly depends on how rigid/paranoid you want to be, since JS is naturally very permissive about dynamic changes. So here are just some ideas to start with:

### Constant protected by accessor methods

If you want to throw an error when an undefined constant is accessed (rather than returning `undefined` and having it fail fifteen steps later) then consider:

```
var createLightweightConstantHolder = function(){
    
    // Because it's nestled in this method, we're protected from the evil outside world.
    var constants  = {        
        FOO : "hello",
        BAR : [1,2,3]
    };
    
    return function(cname){
        if(typeof cname == "undefined"){
            // Gives all constants back at once, in case someone needs to iterate
            return lang.clone(constants);
        }else{
            // Value of a particular thing
            if(constants.hasOwnProperty(cname)){
                return constants[cname];
            }else{
                throw "Constant '"+cname+"' does not exist.";
            }
        }
    }
};

var stuff = createLightweightConstantHolder();

stuff("FOO"); // Returns "hello"
stuff("BAZ"); // Throws a descriptive exception 
var copyOfUnderlyingValues = stuff();
```

This is sort of ugly because you're passing constant names as strings, but it DOES fail fast and prevent modifications.

### Constants using `Object.freeze`

This one uses a relatively new feature of "freezing" objects. Please note that it only freezes the top-level object to prevent adding/removing/replacing values. Changes to non-scalars are still possible.

```
var constants  = {        
    FOO : "hello",
    BAR : [1,2,3],
    BAZ : {"x","y"}
};

constants = Object.freeze(constants);

/*
 *  Some things which do/don't work: 
 */
constants.FOO; // Is "hello"

constants.FOO = "goodbye"; // Won't change. Depending on env and strict-mode, may throw an error or else silently fail.

constants.OOPS; // Is undefined, does NOT throw an error when access it.

constants.BAR.push(4); // DOES alter array items

constants.BAZ.x = "z"; // DOES alter object properties
```

This won't be available on all platforms, check the browser/environment compatibility charts.